# How to configure scalatest to display all logging messages

Tags: scalatest

I have set up a log4j on DEBUG level for both console appender and a file appender. However only the Scalatest summary is showing up.

The tests being run are under a project in the srce/catalyst module.  Here is the sql/catalyst/src/test/resources/log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA, FA

#Console Appender
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p %c: %m%n
log4j.appender.CA.Threshold =DEBUG 
log4j.appender.CA.target=System.err

#File Appender
log4j.appender.FA=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FA.append=false
log4j.appender.FA.file=target/unit-tests.log
log4j.appender.FA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Set the logger level of File Appender to WARN
log4j.appender.FA.Threshold = INFO

# Some packages are noisy for no good reason.
log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazyStruct=false
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazyStruct=OFF

log4j.additivity.org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler=false
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler=OFF

log4j.additivity.hive.ql.metadata.Hive=false
log4j.logger.hive.ql.metadata.Hive=OFF

# Parquet related logging
log4j.logger.parquet.hadoop=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.sql.parquet=INFO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be:

```
 -DforkMode=never
```

Otherwise the logging statements do not appear.  I discovered this answer when trying to fix another issue - that breakpoints were not respected.  Turning on single-threaded mode using the above option fixed both problems.

Comment: is this a VM option? I'm having the same issue but in IntelliJ IDEA with the ScalaTest plugin.